# Express a relation as a function $f: A \to \mathcal{P} (A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Explicitly give the "$\leq$" relation shown in the following graph as a function from $A$ to $\mathcal{P} (A)$.

[image: leq relation]

I think this is an odd question as I don't think this is even technically a function because it violates the following condition:

$$ if \; (a,b) \in g \; and \; (a,b') \in g \Rightarrow b=b' $$

Is this right? (Try 2)

For $a,b \in A$ and $A  = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$

$$ f(a) := \{ b \in A : a \leq b \} $$

Then for example

$$ f(1) = \{1,2,3,4\} $$

Then would taking the cross product give the desired ordered pairs?

$$ at \; a=1: \; 1 \times f(1) =  \{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4) \} $$

Then would $g := a \times f(a)$ be the kind of function they are asking?  I think closer because now  $g \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $g: A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$

Comment: I think this looks better: $f(a):=\{b\in A|b \leq a\}$.

Supposing $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the power set, then your codomain is not the set of ordered pairs of $A$, but the set of _subsets_ of $A$.

Comment: did you mean $a \leq b$?

Comment: well, no... I very well can't use that $a$ as varying, when it's the argument of $f$...

Comment: but as you defined wouldn't this give $f(1) = \{0,1\}$?

Comment: Isn't that what we want? To get the set of all elements in relation with the argument?

Comment: Yes, but in the picture, (and I should have mentioned in my question) that I think the circles with $x$'s indicate the values of the function evaluated on the horizontal axis, so on the horizontal axis, at $a=1$ the corresponding values on the vertical axis are s.t. $a \leq f(a)$ are $f(a) = \{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: Ah, then yes, it would be $b \geq a$

Comment: nps!  your definition of $f$ still helped me(:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not right.

1. First of all $f$ is not a function. $(1,2)$ and $(1,4)$ are both elements of $f$, which means that $f$ is not a function. What you defined is essentially $\leq$ again.
2. The goal is to define a function which takes an element and returns a set. So you need to ask yourself what sort of set you can associate each element that will tell you, essentially, how to reconstruct the relation again. You're on the right track, but you're supposed to have a set output.

Comment: Hi @Asaf Karagila, thank you for your answer, I've updated my question/answer could you check it please?

Comment: Yes, now you can represent $\leq$ using this function, and you have that $\leq=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}\times f(a)$.